# Different UIViewController logged in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

When user open the app it show login `UIViewController`. When user log in  it redirect to next mapkit `UIViewController`. But when user open app again I would like that he will skip login `UIViewController`. How can I do that? I tried programatically redirect in login method `viewWillAppear` but it works bad(It show controller for second).

[image: Map controller p]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to add this check in the AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if(isLoggedin) {
        Storyboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *mapViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mapViewController" ];
        self.rootViewController = [[UINavigationCotroller alloc] initWithRootViewController:mapViewController];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the login in the `viewWillAppear:` method of the first view controller, do it in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if (loggedIn) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        [navigationController.topViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1to2" sender:navigationController.topViewController];
        return YES;
    }
}
```

where `1to2` is the identifier of the segue from view controller 1 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // replace with your real auth-checking
    if ([self wasAuthorized] == NO) {

        [self showLoginController];

    }

    return YES;

}

- (UIViewController *)mainController {

    UINavigationController *rootNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[self window] rootViewController];
    return [[rootNavigationController viewControllers] firstObject];

}

- (void)showLoginController {

    UIViewController *loginController = [self loginController];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.mainController presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];        

    });

}

- (UIViewController *)loginController {

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    return [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginNavController"];

}
```